# show time from milliseconds by using toLocaleTimeString()

Tags: javascript, string, date, time, locale

I am attempting to show the time using milliseconds. I'm using the `toLocaleTimeString` since it supports the locale.

```js
var milliseconds = 10000;
var date = new Date(milliseconds); 

console.log(date.toLocaleTimeString('en',milliseconds));

// expected result - 0:0:10 AM
// actual result   - 5:30:10 AM
```

The result is not what I'm expected. How can get the expected result using `toLocaleTimeString`

Comment: You should read the MDN article on [*toLocaleTimeString*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46765146/show-time-from-milliseconds-by-using-tolocaletimestring). The second argument should be an options object, not a number.

Answer (score 0):

The normal behaviour of the **[`.toLocaleTimeString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString)** method is to display the time in a string representation based on the `local` time zone of your environment, that's why you got a different result.

And you were passing a wrong argument `milliseconds` to it in:

```
date.toLocaleTimeString('en',milliseconds);
```

Actually the [**Date.prototype.toLocaleTimeString()** method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString) takes an `options` object as a second argument, where you can specify several options including the `timeZone` which specifies the desired time zone for the output.

So call it with `{"timeZone": "UTC"}` to display it in `UTC`, like this:

```
date.toLocaleTimeString('en',{"timeZone": "UTC"})
```

**Demo:**

```js
var milliseconds = 10000;
var date = new Date(milliseconds); 

console.log(date.toLocaleTimeString('en',{"timeZone": "UTC"}));

// expected result - 0:0:10 AM
// actual result   - 5:30:10 AM
```

Comment: Where do we find the prototype definition for the options object? I see people giving examples of the properties on that object, but I cant find what those properties are, or what the compatible values could be.

Comment: @PaulG I juste reffered to the [**MDN docs**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString#using_options), you can find there some examples using `options` .

Comment: Thanks fror the response :) I see the examples there, but I thought there should be some docs somwehere that describe the object completely, e.g. showing the other possible values for each property. Having said that, I did notice that we can get some insight into that via intellisense (VsCode or webstorm at least), so that gets me to where I need to go. I also noticed via intellisense the type of the options object (Intl.DateTimeFormatOptions). Also - it turns out that these types were added relatively recently in this PR on 13 May 2020: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/38522

Comment: Ah Okey, great but I no the MDN docs doesn't have such section.

Answer (score -1):

In `var date = new Date(10000);`, the "10000" unit is always relative to 1970-01-01 00:00:00 in UTC timezone (i.e. add 10000ms from it). Thus, the corresponding time is equivalent to 1970-01-01 00:00:10 UTC.

`date.toLocaleTimeString('en')` output the time in your system timezone, thus gives the difference you found.

One way to fix is to set `date` variable to system timezone by adding the timezone difference in milliseconds, as the following:

`var date = new Date(10000 + new Date().getTimezoneOffset()*60000);`  (`new Date().getTimezoneOffset()` is timezone difference in minutes)